# View Controller too thin for IOS simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

As shown on the pictures, my iOS simulator shows my view controller to be too small for the screen. I can't figure out if there is something wrong with the properties of my view controller, iOS simulator or both ...

Thank you for your help :)

[image: IOS Simulator]
[image: My view controller]

Comment: Hi, you need to set the constraint for the view, that's the problem why your tableView is not stretching depends on the Device's height or width.

Comment: Use autolayout.  No excuses apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design view represents only one possible size, if looks good there it doesn't mean it will look good on all sizes. You say you have 2 options to make your content adapt to different sizes

- Use [autolayout constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- Use [autoresizingmask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask)

Both of them can be set on interface builder for most scenarios. You have to pick one or the other, autolayout contraints provides much more possibilities that autoresizing mask but it's also more complex.

We could say that there is a third option: change sizes view sizes programatically according screen size. In most cases this doesn't make a lot of sense but exists as an option.

Comment: There is no excuse not to use autolayout.  With iOS9, Apple has provided yet another reason to be using autolayout.  By iOS10 or sooner, Apple will probably start rejecting applications that don't use autolayout...

Comment: Would you recommend autolayout over autoresizingmask then ?

Comment: I'd recommend you to use autolayout. Sooner or later you'll have to put your hands on it, you'll have to give it some time to get all the power of it. Fixing your specific problem is quite trivial with autolayout